# comparing cursor values for equality in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

```
declare
  course_id char(10);
  course_idA char(10);

cursor task3 
  is
      select c_id from certificationrequirement
      where pcp_id = 101;

cursor task3A
  is 
      select o.c_id from courseoffering o
      join co_enrolment ce
      on o.co_id = ce.co_id
      where ce.s_regno = 401 and ce.coe_completionstatus = 'P';

Begin
  open task3;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'List of Course to take ');
    loop

      FETCH task3 into course_id;
      exit when task3%NOTFOUND;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( course_id);

    end loop;
  close task3;

  open task3A;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'List of Courses student has passed ');

    loop

      FETCH task3A into course_idA;
      exit when task3A%NOTFOUND;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (course_idA);

    end loop;
  close task3A;

  if (cursor task3 = cursor task3A )
  Then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Student can attempt the Certification exam ');
  Else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Student cannot attempt the Certification exam ');
  END if;
end;
```

I'm using one cursor to list all courses student need to take for particular degree.
Second cursor to list how many courses student have passed for degree he is studying.
If both values in both the cursor are equal he would be eligible to take exit exam otherwise he won't be able to. I have written down the comparing code but I think above is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: Idea is to compare two values whether they are equal or not right? Then why use select statement without using cursors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (task3%rowcount = task3A%rowcount  )
              Then
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Student can attempt the Certification exam ');
              Else
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Student cannot attempt the Certification exam ');
              END if;
```

I figured out answer for my question and it worked perfectly for me :))